# Flutter: Riverpod StateNotifier does not notifies about changed state

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I successfully used `StateNotifier` with primitives and also with non-primitives using a generator. But with the manually written non-primitive type, it does not work. I can see in the debugger that the `setState` method is called, but ConsumerWidget does not reflect any change.

Here is my code:

*notifications_settings_provider.dart*

```
class NotificationsSettingsStateNotifier
    extends StateNotifier<NotificationsSettings> {
  NotificationsSetttingsStateNotifier()
      : super(NotificationsSettings.defaultValues());

  setState(NotificationsSettings val) {
    state = val;
  }
}

final notificationsProvider = StateNotifierProvider<
    NotificationsSettingsStateNotifier, NotificationsSettings>((ref) {
  return NotificationsSettingsStateNotifier();
});
```

*notifications_settings.dart*

```
class NotificationsSettings {
  bool? enabled;
  int? timeoutInDays;
  int? delayInHours;
  String? startTime;

  NotificationsSettings(
      {this.enabled, this.timeoutInDays, this.delayInHours, this.startTime});

  NotificationsSettings.defaultValues() {
    enabled = true;
    timeoutInDays = 1;
    delayInHours = 3;
    startTime = '09:00 AM';
  }

  NotificationsSettings.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    enabled = json['enabled'];
    timeoutInDays = json['timeoutInDays'];
    delayInHours = json['delayInHours'];
    startTime = json['startTime'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['enabled'] = this.enabled;
    data['timeoutInDays'] = this.timeoutInDays;
    data['delayInHours'] = this.delayInHours;
    data['startTime'] = this.startTime;
    return data;
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      other is NotificationsSettings &&
      other.runtimeType == runtimeType &&
      other.enabled == enabled &&
      other.timeoutInDays == timeoutInDays &&
      other.delayInHours == delayInHours &&
      other.startTime == startTime;

  int get hashCode =>
      Object.hash(enabled, timeoutInDays, delayInHours, startTime);
}
```

*notifications_screen.dart*

```
class Notifications extends ConsumerWidget {
 Notifications({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    var notificationsSettings = ref.watch(notificationsProvider);
    ...
    onToggle: (index) {
                  notificationsSettings.enabled = index == 0 ? true : false;
                  ref
                      .read(notificationsProvider.notifier)
                      .setState(notificationsSettings);
```

I thought that it can be somehow related to how StateNotifier internally compares state objects and I have overridden `==` and `hashcode`. Did not help.

Currently, I think that maybe my `NotificationsSettings` object needs `copyWith` method, but does not sure yet.

I know that I can use a code generator, but the question still stands even as purely academic.

Comment: Please stop using StateNotifier.  The literature is rushing to catch up with Remi's prolific development.  In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Literature is running slow. Probably slower than Remi upgrades Riverpod. )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rewriting your `NotificationsSettings` class using the [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) or [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) package.

A simpler way would be to implement all fields of the `NotificationsSettings` class as `final`.

Comment: Final fields it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to Ruble's answer revealed that the problem was that class properties were not defined as `final`.

Now, the class looks as follows:

```
class NotificationsSettings {
  final bool? enabled;
  final int? timeoutInDays;
  final int? delayInHours;
  final String? startTime;

  NotificationsSettings(
      {this.enabled, this.timeoutInDays, this.delayInHours, this.startTime});

  static NotificationsSettings defaultValues() {
    return NotificationsSettings(
      enabled: true, timeoutInDays: 1, delayInHours:1, startTime: '09:00 AM');
  }

  NotificationsSettings fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {

    return NotificationsSettings(
        enabled: json['enabled'] ?? this.enabled,
        timeoutInDays: json['timeoutInDays'] ?? this.timeoutInDays,
        delayInHours: json['delayInHours'] ?? this.delayInHours,
        startTime: json['startTime'] ?? this.startTime,
      );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['enabled'] = this.enabled;
    data['timeoutInDays'] = this.timeoutInDays;
    data['delayInHours'] = this.delayInHours;
    data['startTime'] = this.startTime;
    return data;
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      other is NotificationsSettings &&
      other.runtimeType == runtimeType &&
      other.enabled == enabled &&
      other.timeoutInDays == timeoutInDays &&
      other.delayInHours == delayInHours &&
      other.startTime == startTime;

  int get hashCode =>
      Object.hash(enabled, timeoutInDays, delayInHours, startTime);

  NotificationsSettings copyWith(
          {bool? enabled,
          int? timeoutInDays,
          int? delayInHours,
          String? startTime}) =>
      NotificationsSettings(
        enabled: enabled ?? this.enabled,
        timeoutInDays: timeoutInDays ?? this.timeoutInDays,
        delayInHours: delayInHours ?? this.delayInHours,
        startTime: startTime ?? this.startTime,
      );
}
```

I also added `copyWith` method, as otherwise there is no way to change the state.

BTW, there is online [JSON to Dart converter that generates Dart classes with final fields and copyWith method](https://itsallwidgets.com/json-to-dart-converter-support-null-safety).